# The getter 'length' was called on null when called on Map object

Tags: dart

I forgot to call `json.encode` on my Map object before sending post request.

Wrong code:

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: data, headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
```

Right code:

```
var response = await http.post(url, body: json.encode(data), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
```

On wrong code I got unexpected error:

> The getter 'length' was called on null.

I am trying understand why? `data` is `Map` and it's not null.

Comment: well, you should have a stacktrace, not only the error message. Try debug if you want to see what happens under the hood :)

Comment: Or come with a full running example we can run for you and check.